# Home Page Navigation

Tags: navigation, quick-launch, homepage

I have a very small issue. I have many links in quick launch & and i want some of the links to be non navigable. In other words , i do not want the user to get redirected to a new page after clicking on it.
Please help me solve this issue as it is one of the smallest requirement.
Thank You

Comment: In navigation setting you just have to uncheck 'open in new tab' option for such links.

Comment: Depending how you have built your navigation, with some OOTB navigation options you'd just leave the URL/Link field empty. Hard to judge exactly without you providing us details (e.g. a screenshot of the navi and/or its settings, or further detailing what navigation you use).

Comment: Hi Bhaskar & Moe,

Bhaskar : i could not find any setting named "Navigation Setting" in my Site Settings. Any other suggestions?
Moe : I am currently using quick launch provided by SharePoint. i cannot provide you screenshot but all i can tell you is that i am not using an OOTB solution and even if i left he link empty it still took Home Page link.